Remove duplicate rows, keep first row
I am working with a dataframe on county executives. I want to run a panel study where the unit of analysis is the county-year.
The problem is that sometimes two or more county executives serve during the same year. I want to remove these semi-duplicate rows. I ALWAYS want to keep the county executive that is listed first.
If my initial df is:
df <- data.frame(year= c(2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002),
                  executive.name= c("Johnson", "Smith", "Peters", "Alleghany", "Roberts", "Clarke", "Tollson", "Brown", "Taschen"),
                  district= c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002))

I want to make it look like this
df.neat <- data.frame(year= c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002),
                  executive.name= c("Johnson", "Smith", "Alleghany", "Roberts", "Clarke", "Tollson"),
                  district= rep(c(1001, 1002), each=3))


Not sure how that duplicate question relates. Isn't this question about keeping only the first value and removing all subsequent duplicates? While that one answers how to remove all duplicates? E.g. - df.neat == df[!duplicated(df[c("year","district")]),] seems to match.

You can do group by district and year, then take the first row from each group.
library(dplyr)
df_neat <- df %>%
  group_by(district, year) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()


Or in one line, df |> dplyr::slice(1, .by = c(district, year))

Base R
first = \(x) x[1L]
aggregate(.~year+district, df, first)
#>   year district executive.name
#> 1 2000     1001        Johnson
#> 2 2001     1001          Smith
#> 3 2002     1001      Alleghany
#> 4 2000     1002        Roberts
#> 5 2001     1002         Clarke
#> 6 2002     1002        Tollson


You can achieve this by using the drop_duplicates function in pandas, which will help you remove duplicate rows based on the year and district columns, while keeping the first occurrence. Here's how you can do it in Python:
import pandas as pd

# Create the initial DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002],
    'executive.name': ['Johnson', 'Smith', 'Peters', 'Alleghany', 'Roberts', 'Clarke', 'Tollson', 'Brown', 'Taschen'],
    'district': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002]
})

# Drop duplicates while keeping the first occurrence
df_neat = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['year', 'district'], keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)

# Display the resulting DataFrame
df_neat

The resulting df_neat will look like this:
   year executive.name  district
0  2000        Johnson      1001
1  2001          Smith      1001
2  2002      Alleghany      1001
3  2000        Roberts      1002
4  2001         Clarke      1002
5  2002        Tollson      1002

This code ensures that for each combination of year and district, only the first occurrence of the county executive is kept, effectively removing any semi-duplicate rows.
